# Is there an equivalent of View concept from Boost.Fusion in Boost.Hana?

Tags: c++, boost, metaprogramming, c++14, boost-hana

I was trying to iterate over a user-defined struct with `hana::for_each` and noticed that it gets copied/moved, while `Boost.Fusion` allows you to iterate on the original struct in-place.

I didn't find anything like a `View` concept from `Boost.Fusion` in `Boost.Hana`. How do I apply transformations to sequences without copying/moving them every time?

```
#include <boost/hana.hpp>
#include <iostream>

struct Foo {
    Foo() = default;
    Foo(const Foo&) { std::cout << "copy" << std::endl; }
    Foo(Foo&&) { std::cout << "move" << std::endl; }
};

struct Struct {
    BOOST_HANA_DEFINE_STRUCT(Struct,
        (Foo, foo)
    );
};

int main() {
    Struct s;
    auto m = boost::hana::members(s); // copy constructor invoked
}
```

UPDATE: I tried to use `hana::transform` to apply `std::ref` to the members, but `Struct` is not a `Functior`, so `transform` is not applicable in this case. I was able to achieve the desired behavior using `hana::accessors`, but it looks a bit hacky to me. I wish there was a way to create views.

```
hana::for_each(hana::accessors<Struct>(), [&s](const auto& accessor) {
    const auto& member = hana::second(accessor)(s); // No copying
});
```

Comment: The edit in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34711884/2417774)  by Louis Dionne may be useful (also the discussion in the comments).

Comment: He's probably avoided explicit view support because that's all changing in C++ 2x what with range based STL v2 and gsl::span<T> et al

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jason is correct in saying that there is experimental support for views in Hana. The problem you encounter is a common one, and Hana does not currently address it in an elegant way. I hope that adding views to Hana will make this problem go away by providing both by-value and by-reference semantics to all algorithms where that makes sense. But adding this in a coherent manner is non-trivial, hence the experimental state of the feature.

That being said, you can solve your problem by either using accessors (as you show in your question), or by iterating on the keys associated to the members of the struct instead:

```
#include <boost/hana.hpp>
#include <iostream>
namespace hana = boost::hana;

struct Foo {
    Foo() = default;
    Foo(const Foo&) { std::cout << "copy" << std::endl; }
    Foo(Foo&&) { std::cout << "move" << std::endl; }
};

struct Struct {
    BOOST_HANA_DEFINE_STRUCT(Struct,
        (Foo, foo)
    );
};

int main() {
    Struct s;
    hana::for_each(hana::keys(s), [&s](const auto& key) {
        const auto& member = hana::at_key(s, key); // No copying
    });
}
```

If you want to manipulate the members themselves as a sequence, but do not want to copy them, you can create a sequence of references as follows:

```
#include <boost/hana.hpp>
#include <iostream>
namespace hana = boost::hana;

struct Foo {
    Foo() = default;
    Foo(const Foo&) { std::cout << "copy" << std::endl; }
    Foo(Foo&&) { std::cout << "move" << std::endl; }
};

struct Struct {
    BOOST_HANA_DEFINE_STRUCT(Struct,
        (Foo, foo)
    );
};

int main() {
    Struct s;
    auto members = hana::transform(hana::keys(s), [&s](auto const& key) {
        return std::ref(hana::at_key(s, key));
    });
}
```

`members` will then be a sequence of `std::reference_wrapper`s that you can carry around, but you'll have to use `.get()` when accessing them. In a future version of Hana, `hana::members` would probably return a view of key/value pairs, where the value is a reference to the original member. But there are a couple of issues that must be resolved before this is possible.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

As far as views are concerned, there are some undocumented features in `boost/hana/experimental/view.hpp` so they certainly appear to be on the horizon for Boost.Hana.

The current problem with `Struct` is that it is `Foldable` on key value pairs. In `hana::unpack` it will put each value from your struct in a pair, creating a copy. Your solution using `hana::accessors` is currently the way to go IMO.

Note that there is currently an open issue for this: https://github.com/boostorg/hana/issues/175